# How do I send data from child component to parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

And I have a parent component code

```
const Drawer = props => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { history } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [dialogOpen,setDialogueOpen] = React.useState(false)

  const handleDialogueOpen = () => {
    setDialogueOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>

        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            XYZ
          </Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleDialogueOpen}>Filter</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      


      <DialogBox dilaogOpenProp={dialogOpen}/>

    </Box>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Drawer);
```

I have a child component

```
const DialogBox = (props) => {

  const [dialogOpenState, setOpen] = React.useState(props.dilaogOpenProp);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(props.dilaogOpenProp);
  }, [props.dilaogOpenProp]);

  const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setOpen(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        onClose={() => {}}
        open={dialogOpenState}
        maxWidth="xs"
        sx={{
          backdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Example Dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>Example Content Here</DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleDialogClose}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}

export default DialogBox;
```

As you can see **DialogBox** is child to **Drawer** both are saved in different file DialogBox.js & Drawer.js

I am able to send boolean value via prop named *dilaogOpenProp* in **DialogBox** and able to change **dialogOpenState** value but I have also created a method in child component **handleDialogClose()** which is changing the value of boolean value of **dialogOpenState** in local state ,Since its value is also used by parent component in variable name **dialogOpen** to track state but its not getting updated and its creating UI error

How do I update **dialogOpen** in parent and **dilaogOpenState** in child at same time during invocation of its child method **handleDialogClose()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Drawer.js**

```
const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setDialogueOpen(false)
  }
     ....
      <DialogBox dilaogOpenProp={dialogOpen} handleDialogCloseProp={handleDialogClose} />
```

DialogBox.js

```
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        onClose={() => {}}
        open={props.dilaogOpenProp}
        maxWidth="xs"
        sx={{
          backdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Example Dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>Example Content Here</DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={props.handleDialogCloseProp}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
```

There is no need of useState. You can do it by props.